# How to create dynamic panel column content?

Tags: routes, panels

Hello i am  new to drupal and trying to make a dynamic column content using [panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels),
so i had created a two columns the right side one is a menu and left side one is about to be dynamic, so when we click a link in the right side menu the content will be rendered in the left side one and we keep the right side menu visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "dynamic", do you mean "only that panel pane changes and the page doesn't reload"?

If so, check https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_ajax_load and this tutorial http://www.stevepolitodesign.com/blog/load-content-drupal-ajax-without-coding .

If you don't need that functionality, then enable the panel page that overrides /node/%node and put your fields in the left side and your menu in the right.

Comment: yes i didn't need to load it ajax just need to render the content, it seems to me working fine, but one more problem that not all types of nodes needs to be overrides, can i control what nodes to be overrided?

Comment: Each panel has got variants. In the variant, you go to selection rules and add  "Node: type Node being viewed is type "Your content type". This allows you to have different panel setups per content type.